# Can not scan some string in wordpress with LOCO TRANSLATE plugin in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some problem with LOCO TRANSLATE plugin. I used LOCO to scan some string in my theme (DIVI theme). It look great!. But some case such as comment section in the post (comment is default function in post in wordpress). It can not scan. Please see the below example:

[image]

Please help me!!! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw my problem. Because my site have not the .po and .mo file in **/wp-content/languages** directory. So the LOCO-TRANSLATE plugin could not find them.

**THE SOLUTION:**

Access to dashboard and go to settings->General. Select the language which you want to use in the Site Language section. The .po file and .mo file will be auto downloaded and auto put into **/wp-content/languages** directory.

**DEMO HERE:**

[image]